# How to publish a WSDL definition with dynamic soap:address location using Spring-WS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

I want to change the `<soap:address location="..."/>` of WSDLs depending on the environment that holds them. For example:

Development: `<soap:address location="https://development.xxx.yyy.zz/abc/ws/"/>`

Testing: `<soap:address location="https://testing.xxx.yyy.zz/abc/ws/"/>`

Production: `<soap:address location="https://production.xxx.yyy.zz/abc/ws/"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a WSDL base file and just change the SOAP address location attribute depending on environment, use this class:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.Wsdl11Definition;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class DynamicUrlWsdlDefinition implements Wsdl11Definition, InitializingBean {

  private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS_LOCATION_XPATH_EXPRESSION = "/definitions/service/port/address/@location";

  private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS_LOCATION_URI_PART_1 = "https://";

  private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS_LOCATION_URI_PART_3 = ".xxx.yyy.zz/abc/ws/";

  private String wsEnvironment;

  private SimpleWsdl11Definition delegate;

  public DynamicUrlWsdlDefinition() {
    this.setDelegate(new SimpleWsdl11Definition());
  }

  @Override
  public Source getSource() {
    try {
      final DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      final DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      final Document document = documentBuilder.parse(((SAXSource) this.getDelegate().getSource()).getInputSource());

      final XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
      final Node locationAttributeNode = (Node) xPath.compile(SOAP_ADDRESS_LOCATION_XPATH_EXPRESSION)
          .evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
      locationAttributeNode.setTextContent(SOAP_ADDRESS_LOCATION_URI_PART_1 + this.getWsEnvironment() + SOAP_ADDRESS_LOCATION_URI_PART_3);

      return new DOMSource(document);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return this.getDelegate().getSource();
    }
  }

  private String getWsEnvironment() {
    if (!StringUtils.hasText(wsEnvironment) || "${ws.environment}".equals(wsEnvironment)) {
      this.setWsEnvironment("NO_DEFINED");
    }
    return wsEnvironment;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    this.getDelegate().afterPropertiesSet();
  }

  public void setWsdl(final Resource wsdlResource) {
    this.getDelegate().setWsdl(wsdlResource);
  }

  private SimpleWsdl11Definition getDelegate() {
    return delegate;
  }

  private void setDelegate(final SimpleWsdl11Definition delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  public void setWsEnvironment(final String wsEnvironment) {
    this.wsEnvironment = wsEnvironment;
  }

}
```

And declare this Spring bean:

```
<bean id="pingoServiceWsdl" class="DynamicUrlWsdlDefinition">
    <property name="wsdl" value="classpath:/pingoService.wsdl"/>
    <property name="wsEnvironment" value="${ws.environment}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Remember to set `MessageDispatcherServlet` `transformWsdlLocations` property to false in order to make this solution work.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same requirement and was not satisfied with the given solution as time has passed by. Actually, in my project, I am using spring-boot 2.2.5.RELEASE and I have managed setting location URI as follows:

```
    @Bean(name = "MyServiceWsdl")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema countriesSchema) 
    {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("MyServiceSoapBinding");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("https://www.kleenxcoder.com/xml/myproject");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("xxx.xxx.xxxx:8080/service/MyService");
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, @kleenxcoder, this solution is ok if you want Spring to generate the wsdl from some schema. You have put wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri() twice.

Comment: Hi @leaqui you are completely correct. That what happens if you copy/paste your code. Many Thx I'll remove the duplicate row immediately.