# Spring WS SOAP webservices change address at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws

I am in process of creating SOAP services by going contract first using WSDL and I am using Spring WS to implement this. However, for my requirement I want to configure the SOAP Address URL dynamically by reading it from a properties file. Can someone help me on how we can achieve this in Spring-WS.

Using the official example I have tried using DefaultWsdl11Definition.setLocationUri(...) but that doesn't seem to work.

```
@Bean(name = "countries")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema countriesSchema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CountriesPort");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/countries1");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
    return wsdl11Definition;
}
```

Comment: You can look at this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479912/how-to-use-spring-web-services-dynamic-wsdl-generation-in-spring-boot

Comment: I have static wsdl's using which I am producing the service. What I am looking for is an equivalent of https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxws/EndpointImpl.html in Spring WS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939937/how-to-publish-a-wsdl-definition-with-dynamic-soapaddress-location-using-spring   This should help